# Formatting command output in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the "dir" output for a given path using Powershell but I'm having a hard time trying to get the desired format. I'm new to Powershell so any suggestions on the command that I've used will also be very helpful to me.

Command used

```
 $dirs  = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $path | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Split("`n")
```

Output I get

```
    Directory: D:\GetDataTest





d-----         3/4/2018   6:02 PM                dir1                                                             

d-----         3/4/2018   6:02 PM                dir2                                                             

-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_1                                                           

-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_2                                                           





    Directory: D:\GetDataTest\dir1





-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_1                                                           

-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_2                                                           





    Directory: D:\GetDataTest\dir2





-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_1                                                           

-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_2
```

I would like get rid of all the whitespaces as well as the lines that read "Directory: .." before the list of items inside the directory.

The output format that I'm after is

```
d-----         3/4/2018   6:02 PM                dir1                                                             
d-----         3/4/2018   6:02 PM                dir2                                                             
-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_1                                                           
-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_2                                                           
-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_1                                                           
-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_2                                                           
-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_1                                                           
-a----         3/2/2018   3:56 PM           1024 file_2
```

Comment: `dir -R $path | Select-Object -Property Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, Name`

Comment: Thanks a lot @JosefZ

Comment: At the conceptual level, you need to know that the output of GCI  is not the same as the same output as displayed to the screen.  The output of GCI is a stream of objects.  What goes to the screen is a stream of characters.  Very different.

Comment: @JosefZ, quick question, I tried using the property FullName but I'd like to remove the first level. Basically FullName for one of the files is D:\GetDataTest\dir2\file. I'd like to only print dir2\file2 and strip the first level i.e. strip D:\GetDataTest

Comment: To remove the top level directory, you could `dir -R $path | Select-Object -Property Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, @{n='name';e={$_.FullName -replace '^.:\\[^\\]*\\(.*)','$1'}}`.

Comment: Another (as I think important) tip: format cmdlets like `Format-Table` are designed to format output only to the **console**. They are not made to format output to any other target like files or variables. So you should use them only at the very last step in a pipeline to beautify the console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [JoesfZ's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095441/formatting-command-output-in-powershell#comment85196062_49095441), you can specify the properties using [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6):

```
Get-Childitem -R $path | Select-Object -Property Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, Name
```

You can also manipulate the properties using a Name and Expression hashtable, as documented in the link above - for example, to strip out "D:\GetDataTest" from the FullName property:

```
Get-Childitem -R $path |
    Select-Object -Property @{Name = "PartialPath"; Expression = {($_.FullName).Replace("D:\GetDataTest","")}}
```

`Name` and `Expression` can be further abbreviated to `n` and `e`